# Circular checkbox on android in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know how to make a custom renderer for the Xamarin forms checkbox? I want the checkbox to be circular on android devices, like they are on iOS.

I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.3.

Comment: Please check both Solution. hope it heps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is **First Solution** use Library:

your Solution is [Here](https://intelliabb.com/2018/09/20/checkbox-for-xamarin-forms/).

in that you can change your shape as per your need.

here is a Gihub Link  as [Here](https://github.com/Intelliabb/XamarinControls/wiki/Checkbox)

Here is **Second Solution** as per your need here is Check box Renderer in Ellipse Shape.

in Xaml,

```
<CheckBox/>
```

in Android Project, First create new file. i named it **CheckboxRenderer.cs**

set this before namespace:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox), typeof(CheckboxRenderer))]
```

here is my class file,

```
public class CheckboxRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox, Android.Widget.CheckBox>
{
    private Android.Widget.CheckBox checkBox;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.CheckBox> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var model = e.NewElement;
        checkBox = new Android.Widget.CheckBox(Context);
        checkBox.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.custom_checkbox);
        checkBox.Tag = this;
        SetNativeControl(checkBox);
    }
}
```

Create these 3 **xml** file in Drawble folder,

1) custom_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
  <item android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

2) checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
          <corners android:radius="1dp" />
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp"
              android:color="#777" />
          <gradient
              android:startColor="#990000"
              android:centerColor="#990000"
              android:endColor="#990000"
              android:angle="270" />
          <size
              android:width="30dp"
              android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>

      <item
          android:width="8dp"
          android:height="2dp"
          android:top="20dp"
          android:left="6dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
          <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
          </shape>
        </rotate>
      </item>

      <item
          android:width="19dp"
          android:height="2dp"
          android:top="16dp"
          android:left="9dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45">
          <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
          </shape>
        </rotate>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

3) unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
  <corners android:radius="1dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#777" />
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#990000"
      android:centerColor="#990000"
      android:endColor="#990000"
      android:angle="270" />
  <size
      android:width="30dp"
      android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

ohh its Done... you will get output like this,

[image: UnChecked]
[image: Checked]

Hope this hepls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried the NuGet Package IntelliAbb, it worked great in the emulators but when I built the project to my iPhone the checkboxes were invisible, I've posted an issue on his GitHub.

I'm going to try the second solution. does it work fine despite android device and screen size?

Comment: @JonathanK : it's pleasure to help you.it will work fine. just try it out and if it's working than please mark this answer true so it can helps to others as well.

Comment: You can use custom renderer in android, IOS part just use native control.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you say "I want the checkbox to be circular on android devices, like they are on iOS." If this is your main goal, you may want to try the [Syncfusion free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) to add a SfCheckbox control. Then you can experiment with the `CornerRadius` property of the checkbox. Here is what worked for me:

```
<StackLayout>
        <checkbox:SfCheckBox Text="Round Checkbox #1" CornerRadius="10" />
        <checkbox:SfCheckBox Text="Round Checkbox #2" CornerRadius="10" IsChecked="True"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]